# Changing set of images in unordered list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change a set of images in an unordered list with jQuery but just can't figure it out. It's a background slideshow so when someone clicks Set2 or Set3, the set of images will change and slideshow will start playing that set of images.

The easiest solution is to link to another page with another slideshow but I'm working on a single page html so it's quite challenging for me. I've tried .html, .replace, .attr but it's just not working or I don't seem to understand. Appreciate if someone could shed some light.

Here's the code that I'm working on.

HTML:

```
    <ul id="slideshow" class="bislideshow">
    <li><img src="image1.jpg" alt="image01"/></li>
    <li><img src="image2.jpg" alt="image02"/></li>
    <li><img src="image3.jpg" alt="image03"/></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li class="set1"><a href="#">SET 1</a></li>
    <li class="set2"><a href="#">SET 2</a></li>
    <li class="set3"><a href="#">SET 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".set1").click(function(){
    //change list images to image3, image4 and image5

    alert("HTML: " + $(".bislideshow").html()); /* Display list to check if image sets are loaded */
    });

    $(".set2").click(function(){
    //change list images to image5, image6 and image7

    alert("HTML: " + $(".bislideshow").html()); /* Display list to check if image sets are loaded */
    });

    $(".set3").click(function(){
    //change list images to image8, image9 and image10

    alert("HTML: " + $(".bislideshow").html()); /* Display list to check if image sets are loaded */
    });
    });
```

});

My jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nn49J/

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: Hi Sudharsan, 
- When someone click Set2, image1, image2 and image3 will be replaced with image4, image5 and image6.

- When someone click Set3, all the 3 images will be replaced too.

Comment: are these set of images are fixed for each Set i.e. set1, set2 and set3 and are they available when page loads?

Comment: Hi Bhushan, so when page loads, image1, 2 and 3 will be default images for the gallery. Only when they click on set1, 2 or 3, then image1,2 and 3 will be replaced. I'm building categories for the slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

JSFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/5DM2w/3/

```
$(function() {
    $img1 = $( "#slideshow > li:nth-child(1) > img" );
    $img2 = $( "#slideshow > li:nth-child(2) > img" );
    $img3 = $( "#slideshow > li:nth-child(3) > img" );
    $(".set1").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault() ;
        $img1.attr({'src':'image1.jpg','alt':'image01'});
        $img2.attr({'src':'image2.jpg','alt':'image02'});
        $img3.attr({'src':'image3.jpg','alt':'image03'});
    });
    $(".set2").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault() ;
        $img1.attr({'src':'image4.jpg','alt':'image04'});
        $img2.attr({'src':'image5.jpg','alt':'image05'});
        $img3.attr({'src':'image6.jpg','alt':'image06'});
    });
    $(".set3").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault() ;
        $img1.attr({'src':'image7.jpg','alt':'image07'});
        $img2.attr({'src':'image8.jpg','alt':'image08'});
        $img3.attr({'src':'image9.jpg','alt':'image09'});
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Naota,

Thanks so much for the solution. It works! 
Could you explain what's 
1. function(e)? 
2. e.preventDefault() ?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @RezaSan, Thanks. You can read about it here .http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ In this case,default click action is prevented.  `preventDefault()` prevents a browser from jumping to `href="#"`.